# Image upload not working in CKEditor when multiple CKEditor field is used

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, lotus-domino, ckeditor4.x

CKEditor Image upload is working for the first field and it is not working for the other fields in traditional Domino Form. The demo app can be seen here. https://dontpanic82.blogspot.com/2009/09/finally-ckeditor-integration-with-lotus.html

I have two fields Field1 and Field2. Image upload is working for Field1. But when the "Send to Server" button clicked in Field2, It throws below error.

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getDialog' of undefined or null reference

[image: Error when "send it to the server clicked"]

The above error is showing in ckeditor.js which is core-js for CKEditor. When we hide Field2 from the page, Then Field2 works without any error. Please help me to fix this issue. I already spent a lot of time on this.